# Can I customize the amount of memory on an Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: memory, azure, virtual-machine

I was looking at the Azure [full calculator](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full) and did not see a slider for adjusting the memory. Do they allow customized memory size or am I stuck with these silly per-configurations? I want at the minimum 16GB with the ability to go much higher like 300GB+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are five sizes (extra small, small, medium, large, and extra large), and they're fixed. Extra large is a 16GB VM, but after overhead of the OS, you only get 14GB.

Other sizes may appear over time, but it's unlikely you'll see 300GB any time soon. Windows Azure uses commodity servers, and they don't have nearly that much RAM.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the cloud has a very long way to go.

Comment: "A long way to go" depends on where you think the destination is.